# Do I need to do co-partitioning If i want to do KStream-KTable Join in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm new to Kafka streams and trying to understand the joins.

Now my question is if I want to do KStream-KTable Join in Kafka streams, do I need to do co-partitioning?

Comment: can someone help me understand why this is marked for close?

Comment: Joins are documented quite well in the Confluent documentation. It is full of why and when you data needs to be repartitioned, but to give you at least a hint: Data in the kafka topics is normally distributed over multiple partitions. A stream processor gets a partition assigned to work on. To bring together data from one topic with another (i.e. Join it) the data has to be partitioned the same way. Otherwise you would maybe have records with keys 1, 3 and 5 from topic A and records with keys 2, 4 from topic B, so the data would not be joined.

Comment: Please read https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/partition-data.html
and: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join

"Data must be co-partitioned: The input data for both sides must be co-partitioned."

Comment: Thanks @JanHeld for the links. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes every non gktable join need co-partitioning